# click events not working with current version of aframe [1.0.3]

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

I am exploring in Augmented reality using A-Frame and ar.js in that I am currently working with interactions  part of 3d-models or primitives.My requirement is on every click of the object or primitive it has to increase its size.But the click events are not working with the current version of A-frame.

Code link for click events [click](https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/how-to-handle-click-events-on-ar-js-58fcacb77c4) .

A-Frame latest version cdn [link](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/).

My code  [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/able-empress-iuumq1gj8n?path=index.html:1:15)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the cursor component and specify which objects will respond to the raycast, (in this case #button) and set this in the opening scene tag: ie.

```
<a-scene  cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: #button">
```

And set the "object" id (in our case '#button') in the script ie.

```
<script>
        var toggleEl = document.querySelector('#button')
        toggleEl.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            toggleEl.emit("clicked"); 
        });
    </script>
```

and finally trigger the event in the actual entity animation to respond to the emitted string in our case "clicked"
`startEvents: clicked` (this used to be begin = "clicked")

In this case the id of your primitive or object will be set to `id = "button"`

Comment: I tried It,but it is not working.when i charge version number to (0.9.2) the click event is working fine.